# Laravel Model::find() throws SQLSTATE error

Tags: php, orm, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to fetch a record from the database using Eloquent CRM. My table's primary key field name is `"user_id"`. The weird thing is that everytime i use `User::find()` and pass a `user_id` number, i get

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' 
(SQL: select * from `users` where `id` = ? limit 1) (Bindings: array ( 0 => 8, ))
```

I'm assuming the ORM makes calls assuming the table's id field name is `"id"` instead of `"user_id"`. How can i check that it correctly sees what it is supposed to see. I also tried to change the primary key field user_id to "id" as the ORM seem to expect and that worked but i'm following a naming convention in my database schema so i will like to stick to `"user_id"`.

Any form of help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the problem. All i had to do was read the documentation properly. Sorry for rushing to ask a question this simple.

Eloquent assumes the primary key field for any table is named "id" by default. To change that, just override the $primaryKey field to the corresponding field name in the database table.

Answer (score -1):

```
class User extends Eloquent implements ....

    public $publicKey = 'user_id';

    ...
```

Comment: It's not $publicKey that you want to set, it's $primaryKey. And it should be protected to so one can change it, not Public.